# How to programmatically add index->value to a chain in php

Tags: php, iterable, chaining

This is my first question here, so please give me hints on bettering my question formulation, etc.
I have already tried searching everywhere online, and I think the answer is out there, but my biggest problem is, I have no idea what words to use to search for this issue.

Now to the problem:
I am currently using:
https://github.com/sokil/php-mongo
To create a searcher that is supposed to be searching through a list of key/values in a mongodb database collection.

My current code looks like this (Yes, way to many arguments, etc. I know, but I am creating a drop in replacement of a legacy function that is just too slow):

```
   public function searchTasks(
       int $start = 1, 
       int $end = 25,
       string $type = null,
       string $taskID = null,
       string $siteID = null,
       string $subject = null,
       ....... //Many more arguments following, but unused so far.
       ): \sokil\mongo\Cursor
   {
       return $this->collection
           ->find()
           ->where('siteID', $siteID)
           ->where('subject', $subject)
           ->whereGreaterOrEqual('status', 0);
   }
```

The problem is, I would like to only add "where" clauses, whenever an argument is not null, so something like:

```
   public function searchTasks(
       int $start = 1, 
       int $end = 25,
       string $type = null,
       string $taskID = null,
       string $siteID = null,
       string $subject = null,
       ....... //Many more arguments following, but unused so far.
       ): \sokil\mongo\Cursor
   {
       $arguments = []
       if($type != null) {
           array_push($arguments, ["type" => $type]);
       }
       return $this->collection
           ->find()
           ->where($arguments)
           ->whereGreaterOrEqual('status', 0);
   }
```

But according to the documentation, this is not possible, and I have found no way to simply add wildcards like this:

```
   public function searchTasks(
       int $start = 1, 
       int $end = 25,
       string $type = "*",
       string $taskID = "*",
       string $siteID = "*",
       string $subject = "*",
       ....... //Many more arguments following, but unused so far.
       ): \sokil\mongo\Cursor
   {
       return $this->collection
           ->find()
           ->where('siteID', $siteID)
           ->where('subject', $subject)
           ->whereGreaterOrEqual('status', 0);
   }
```

If you have any way of helping me out with searchwords for what this is called, etc. I will appreciate it a lot.
All the best
Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to fetch (execute) the query you are building. You can add the `where` clauses before executing. Try this:

```
$query = $this->collection->find();

if ($siteID !== null) {
    $query->where('siteID', $siteID);
}

return $query;
```

You then later call `findAll()` **outside** of your function.

Comment: Oh my god I feel useless as a programmer right now. Thank you so much for this, can't believe it is that simple, I just really thought the executing was done with the "find()", and that you had to chain it in one go, i Have no idea why. 
Thank you and have a great day.